# FTP response «550 Permission denied.»

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Hi everyone and thanks in advance.

So I got stuck with **FTP response «550 Permission denied.»**

System: `Ubuntu 14.04` and `vsftpd: version 3.0.2`

I created a `drupal` user for working over FTP, homedir: `/var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com`

Part of `/etc/passwd`:

```
drupal:x:1005:65034::/var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com:/bin/false
```

VSFTPD conf **/etc/vsftpd.conf**:

```
listen=YES
listen_port=xxxx
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/nchroot
log_ftp_protocol=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=x.x.x.x
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
```

All /etc/pam.d/vsftpd:

```
auth    sufficient  pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

I tried to change permissions to 777 and the owner to drupal:drupal on `/var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/htdocs`

Connection to FTP server seems to work and I can see a list of proper files
and dirs, however I can't create a file.

In vsftpd logs I get: FTP response «550 Permission denied.»

Google keeps on telling me that it's either a permissions issue, or vsftpd.conf
missconfiguration in

```
write_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

But in my case everything is set.

I'm thinking that I'm missing something in **/etc/pam.d/vsftpd** as it's customized by other guy.

Comment: What does `ls -l /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com` show?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the guest_username option, the vsftpd.conf file needs to have the following line added:

virtual_use_local_privs=YES

from the manual:

**virtual_use_local_privs**
    If enabled, virtual users will use the same privileges as local users. By default, virtual users will use the same privileges as anonymous users, which tends to be more restrictive (especially in terms of write access).

```
Default: NO
```